# I’m striking a line through the irrelevant sections

Tags: british-english

What this line means: "I’m striking a line through the irrelevant sections."

Comment: What did your internet search for that phrase tell you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>Apples are red or green.</s> That is irrelevant to my answer, so I've *struck* (or 'stricken') *a line through it*.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if someone is editing a document and is editing out unnecessary text by drawing a line through it (if using pen and paper) or using their computer keyboard on a digital document.